# MVC4 how to save changes of only a select field without affecting others

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an **edit** page were users can update only 2 fields city and state, the whole model has about 11 different fields but again; I only allow them to edit those 2 plus 1 other which is a UniqueID but they can't edit that. My issue is that upon editing and saving the new information all the other fields become NULL in the database for that particular row, what can be causing this? This is my code

```
        [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
          //Get user uniqueID
        var ss = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
// basically look up uniqueID match in database and select 3 fields profileID,city,state
        string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["looglercontext"].ConnectionString;
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            var getinfo = sqlConnection.Query<profile>("Select profileID,city,state from profiles where profileID=@myprofile", new { myprofile = ss }).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(getinfo);
        }
    }
```

My view looks like this

```
     @model hackerway.Models.profile
using (Html.BeginForm("edit", "profile", FormMethod.Post
{




 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.profileID)


                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.city)
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.state)



 <div style="margin-left: 200px">
    <p class="name">
        <input type="submit" name="myedit" value="update" /> 

    </p>



  </div>
 }
```

After the user clicks the update button then we go to the simple HttpPost

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(profile profiler)
    {

              // I use the profiler to get the fields from the view and update them
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        db.Entry(profiler).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        ViewBag.success = "Your changes have been saved";
                        return View(profiler);
                    } 


     }
```

As stated before everything works if a field gets updated the changes get saved but the other 11 fields that i'm nut putting in the form return to 'Null'. In the SQL code I am only grabbing the fields that I need hence the reason I didn't use ***** any help would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're understanding of how the data moves back and forth between your database isn't quite right.  Selecting only the fields you need from the database is absolutely correct; there's nothing wrong with that.

Where your code needs to change is in your `POST` method.  Your method takes in a `profile` typed parameter.  When the data from your HTML form is submitted to the server, only the inputs from your form are passed to the server (i.e. `profileId`, `city` and `state`).  Any other properties on the `profiler` object will be null because how else is ASP.NET supposed to know what they are?  The user only passed on those three values.

In the Entity Framework world the way to solve this is to do something like the following:

```
public ActionResult Edit(profile profiler)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Go fetch the existing profile from the database
        var currentProfile = db.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProfileId == profiler.ProfileId);
        //Update the database record with the values from your model
        currentProfile.City = profiler.City;
        currentProfile.State = profiler.State;
        //Commit to the database!
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.success = "Your changes have been saved";
        return View(profiler);
    }
}
```

To give a complete answer, there *is* another way to solve the issue.  However, I would highly recommend you don't do this and I'll explain why shortly.

The other way to solve the issue is to add additional hidden inputs on your form for any other fields in your table.  By doing so, when the user submits the form ASP.NET's model binding process will make sure that the other properties on your `profiler` object have data.  When you commit the object to the database, at that point you already have everything that you need.

Why is this a bad idea?  Let's say I load up your page and I want to try changing data that I'm not supposed to.  I could modify the values of those hidden inputs, submit the form, and you're application would commit that data to the database!  Bad news bears.  By using hidden inputs you are putting trust in your user.  In some cases that may be an acceptable risk (e.g. a little web app for your co-worker), but in other cases it could be high risk or even fraudulent.

It also adds unnecessary overhead in terms of bytes traveling over the wire, but that's a minor detail in comparison to the latter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, it worked perfectly. I now see how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation  on hidden fields, this code helped me a lot.